# How to include appropriate SCSS file?

Tags: vue.js, sass, app-themes

I'm using Vue and I have multiple stylesheets for different configuration. And I need to use only one of them (depending on the configuration).

I have config file with value `type: "a"`, so that I need to include and use `"a-setup.scss"`. I tried to include file in `vue.config.js`, but it doesn't support imports.

So the question is: what should I do to use certain scss file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I found is to use css additionalData prop inside the `vue.config.js`. Code:

```js
const filename = process.env.VUE_APP_TEMPLATE;

const additionalData =
  ... +
  `@import "src/assets/styles/setup/${ filename }.scss";`;

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: { additionalData }
    }
  },
  ...
 }
```